# A property of the convergents of the continued fraction expansion of a rational number

Tags: number-theory, inequality, rational-numbers, cryptography, continued-fractions

I'm looking for a proof of the following result (theorem 6.14 of the book *Cryptography. Theory and practice* by Paterson and Stinson):

> **Theorem 6.14** *Suppose that $\text{gcd}(a,b) = \text{gcd}(c,d) = 1$ and:* $$\Bigl\rvert \frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d}\Bigr\rvert < \frac{1}{2d^2}$$ *Then $c/d$ is one of the convergents of the continued fraction expansion of $a/b$*.

I already know the analogous result for irrational numbers (theorem 7.14 of the book *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by Niven, Zuckerman and Montgomery with a slight change of notations to avoid ambiguities):

> **Theorem 7.14** *Let $\xi$ denote any irrational number. If there is a rational number $c/d$ with $d \geq 1$ such that:* $$\Bigl\rvert \xi - \frac{c}{d} \Bigr\rvert < \frac{1}{2d^2}$$ *Then $c/d$ equals one of the convergents of the continued fraction expansion of $\xi$*.

However, it seems to me that the proof of theorem 7.14 cannot immediately be generalized to the case of rational numbers: one calls $h_j/k_j$ the $j$-th convergent of the simple continued fraction expansion of $\xi$ and then one uses the fact that $\lim k_j = +\infty$ to pick an integer $n$ such that $k_n \leq b < k_{n+1}$. This cannot be done in the case of rational numbers (theorem 6.14) simply because the convergents of the continued fraction expansion of $a/b$ are finite: it might be the case that the convergents of $a/b$ are $h_0/k_0,h_1/k_1,\dots,h_m/k_m = a/b$ and that $b \leq d$. So, how exactly is theorem 6.14 established?

Comment: I would like to inform you that while Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, [more than just a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/) is expected from the asker. If you can, include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. If you are stuck, provide definitions and your own background. Write down what you know and generally try to be constructive. If you can, provide motivation and context for the problem. This is meant to be an exchange, both ways, as the site name implies. To start, you could e.g. tell us what you already know about continued fractions.

Comment: Probably look an iny number theory book that covers continued fractions ... for exampe *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, Niven, Zuckerman, Montgomery

Comment: Ok, sorry. Now it should be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, the claim also holds for irrational numbers. I will give a proof that works for all real numbers, i.e. I will prove:

---

Let $x\in\mathbb R$ and $c,d\in\mathbb Z$ coprime such that $$\left|x-\frac cd\right|<\frac1{2d^2}.$$ Then $\frac cd$ is a convergent of the continued fraction expansion of $x$.

---

Proof: If $x=\frac cd$, the claim is obvious. Otherwise write
$$x-\frac cd=\varepsilon\cdot\frac{\theta}{d^2},\qquad \varepsilon=\pm1,\ 0<\theta<\frac12.$$
Let $\frac cd=[a_0;a_1,\ldots,a_n]$ be the (finite) continued fraction expansion of $\frac cd$. Since one can vary the length of such an expansion by $1$, wlog assume $(-1)^n=\varepsilon$. Write $\frac{u_k}{v_k}=[a_0;a_1,\ldots,a_k]$ for the $k$-th convergent of $\frac cd$, with $u_k,v_k$ coprime. Then let
\begin{align}\xi:=\frac{v_{n-1}x-u_{n-1}}{-dx+c}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad x=\frac{c\xi+u_{n-1}}{d\xi+v_{n-1}}.\tag{$\ast$}\end{align}

A short calculation, using the well-known formula $u_kv_{k-1}-u_{k-1}v_k=(-1)^{k+1}$, now gives
$$\varepsilon\cdot\frac{\theta}{d^2}=x-\frac cd=\frac{\varepsilon}{d(d\xi+v_{n-1})} \quad\Longrightarrow \quad\frac1\theta=\xi+\frac{v_{n-1}}d.$$
Now since $\frac1\theta>2$ and $\frac{v_{n-1}}d=\frac{v_{n-1}}{v_n}<1$ (denominators of convergents are increasing), we conclude that $\xi>1$. Equation ($\ast$) implies that $x=[a_0;a_1,\ldots,a_n,\xi]$ and since $\xi>1$ we can indeed conclude that the continued fraction expansion of $x$ starts with $[a_0;a_1,\ldots,a_n,\ldots]$.

---

**Edit** (sketch of proofs of basic formulas, as requested): Let $x=[a_0;a_1,\ldots,a_n,\xi]$ with $a_0\in\mathbb Z$, $a_i\in\mathbb N$, $\xi\in\mathbb R$. Then one easily proves by induction that $x=\frac uv$ with $u$ and $v$ given by $$\binom uv=A_0\cdots A_n\binom\xi1,\qquad A_k:=\begin{pmatrix}a_k&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ Now let $x=[a_0;a_1,\ldots]$ be a continued fraction expansion, and denote the convergents as $\frac{u_k}{v_k}$. Then by the equation above one infers that $$\begin{pmatrix}u_n&u_{n-1}\\v_n&v_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}=A_0\cdots A_n.$$ Taking determinants now gives the "well-known formula" cited in the proof. Combining these two equations gives $$\binom uv=\begin{pmatrix}u_n&u_{n-1}\\v_n&v_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\binom\xi1\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{u_n\xi+u_{n-1}}{v_n\xi+v_{n-1}},$$ which is $(\ast)$. Combining this with the first statement of the edit, we get that ($\ast$) holds if and only if $x=[a_0;a_1,\ldots,a_n,\xi]$. (The only if part follows since $\xi$ is uniquely determined by these formulas.)

Comment: Why $0 < \theta < 1/2$ such that $x - c/d = \epsilon \cdot \theta/d^2$ exists? And I don't understand the last step either. How exactly equation $(\ast)$ implies that $x = [a_0;a_1,\dots,a_n,\xi]$? Also, if you manage to prove that, then we are done, so I don't see why we should observe that $\xi > 1$ in the first place.

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is the sign of $x-\frac cd$. Also, $|x-\frac cd|$ is smaller than $\frac1{2d^2}$, so it is $\frac{\theta}{d^2}$ for some $\theta<\frac12$. For your second question I hoped you already would know that, I'll edit the answer. Finally, we need $\xi>1$ because otherwise there would be a $0$ in the continued fraction which is not allowed.